# Feign response returns body null when error code is 401 Unauthorized

Tags: http, client, response, unauthorized, netflix-feign

When i get 401 unauthorized response, there is no body part in errordecoder response object. If i change only status code of the response for example to 403 or anything else in server side, then there is no problem. Also tried from Postman Rest Client and there is no problem too. I digged up the Client class of feign and errorstream and inputstream always null when status code is 401 but content length seems true.
Any idea?